# Spinner not working in ListView

Tags: android-listview, android-spinner

I am customizing ListView and in its row I am using Spinner.Although list displays properly but when I click on Spinner it throws an exception.

```
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:260)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-22 17:11:08.705: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved problem my own.

In my ArrayAdapter for `ListView` I was using `getApplicationContext()`.I just changed it to `this`.